# Question about linear splines.

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation, spline, interpolation-theory

I have a question about linear splines. A computer package I am using has the option to use linear splines, but there is no user manual I can find.

I am having problems with the kind of inputs the package wants.

- The first input is a vector x with values sorted in ascending order with **N+1** values.  This is ok.
- The second is a vector of zero order coefficients. This vector can be of length **N** or **N+1**. What I do not understand here is that it doesn't have to be of the same length as the x-vector, why is that?
- The third is a vector with the slopes. This vector has to be of length **N**. Again why does it not have to be the same length as the x vector?

Here is a link to the documentation: [link](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.Interpolation/LinearSpline.htm), the relevant info is in the first box under "Public constructors."

So what I am struggling with is that the vectors are of different length. If they were of the same length it would make better sense, because then it would be the x-value and the function value and the slope at each point. But with different lengths, what is is they are actually asking for?

Comment: $N+1$ x-values means you have $N$ subintervals and on each subinterval the slope is constant, so it makes sense that the 3rd argument should have length $N$.

Comment: @Coolwater But why do we even have to provide the slope? When we provide the values the slope can be calculated? And why can the values have length N?

Comment: You can reverse engineer this if you like.